# Inject property value into @ResponseStatus annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

In my microservice Spring Boot project, I have this custom exception annotated with @ResponseStatus  :

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "${message.custom.notFound}")
public class MyCustomAnnotation extends RuntimeException
```

and it works pretty well : when the exception is raised my controller returns the specified status (404), but the reason is not resolved (error message is "${message.custom.notFound}").

Do you know if there is a way to inject a property from a properties file into this annotation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried tracing the usage of ReponseStatus and cannot find anything that will replace this content. The doc recommends the usage of ExceptionHandler due to the involvement of sendError (which flushes the response). https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html

Answer (score 0):

First define message parameter in constructor :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class MyCustomAnnotation extends RuntimeException {
    public MyCustomAnnotation(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then use in controller service like this :

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

 @Value($value.from.properties)
 private String value;

    @PostMapping("/api")
    public ResponseEntity send(@RequestBody requestBody) {
        throw new MyCustomAnnotation(value);
    }

}
```